# Calculation of Site Frequency Spectrum (SFS) using STR data

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, genetics

Hi everyone I had a question on if it is possible to calculate (Site Frequency Spectrum)SFS using STR data. Please mention if you know any programm that can be used for that!

Thank you!

I have tried Arlequin but it doesn't offer this option for STR. Personally I haven't find anything that can do this type of calculation with STR!